# How to define name of the quantile regression plots?

Tags: r, plot

I am using `quantreg` package for quantile regression.
Here is the code I have used for plotting coefficient and intercepts.

```
library(quantreg)

data(engel)
attach(engel)
QR=rq(income~foodexp, tau=seq(0.02, 0.98, by=0.02))
plot(summary(QR))
```

I am getting the plot of Intercept and food expenditure, which is by default written on the above of the plot

How to change the title from food expenditure to something else (say for example, `Return`)? I am unable to write code.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a vector of subplot titles to the `main` parameter:

```
plot(summary(QR), main = c("(Intercept)", "Return"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I need some further help in the above example. In case of three independent variable along with food expenditure, i want to plot only food expenditure coefficient with intercept over the quantiles. Please suggest the code.